# Why downcasting throws ClassCastException in this case?

Tags: java, casting, downcast, upcasting

I have 2 packages: controller and federation. Controller just contains controller class with main method, but federation contains 2 classes, Shuttle (parent class) and MiniShuttle (child class). Upcasting works like a charm, but when I try to downcasting, I get ClassCastException.

This is the code I tried:

Shuttle.java

```
package federation;

public class Shuttle {

    protected int passengers;

}
```

MiniShuttle.java

```
package federation;

public class MiniShuttle extends Shuttle {


}
```

Controller.java

```
package controller;

import federation.MiniShuttle;
import federation.Shuttle;

public class Controller {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shuttle shuttle = new Shuttle();
        MiniShuttle mshuttle = (MiniShuttle)shuttle;

        if(mshuttle instanceof Shuttle)
        {
            System.out.println("ok");
        }else
        {
            System.out.println("not ok");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What if Minishuttle added new instance fields or methods? And what if you tried to use them? You can't expect that a Parent class can behave the same as a child class of theirs.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Okay I get what's your point, but in which cases does downcasting work then?

Comment: `shuttle` is not a `MiniShuttle`.  What makes you think that such a cast would work?

Comment: @AmarKalabić I don't think it ever works. I've never used it. I can't see why it would ever need to be used. If you think you need downcasting, you've probably set things up wrong and need to rethink your design.

Comment: You can't cast an object to a class it is not an instance of. A  `new Shuttle` is not an instance of `MiniShuttle`, so you cannot cast it to one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have instantiated `Shuttle`. Declaration `new Shuttle()` says that object of type `Shuttle` is instantiated, and a reference to this object is `Shuttle` (from `Shuttle shuttle = ...`).
If you want to get this to work, use `Shuttle shuttle = new MiniShuttle()`. With this you are actually saying "I'm instantiating an object of `MiniShuttle` type and upcasting a reference to it to the type of `Shuttle`".

Comment: Thanks, all clear now.

Comment: You are welcome

Answer (score 2):

As you said, you are *down*casting, meaning casting from a parent to a child - it won't work that way because `shuttle` is of type `Shuttle` and not `MiniShuttle`.

You could do it the other way though:

```
MiniShuttle miniShuttle = new MiniShuttle();
Shuttle shuttle = (Shuttle) miniShuttle;
```

That way you are *up*casting and it is perfectly fine because each `MiniShuttle` is `Shuttle` as well.

Answer (score 0):

The contract in OOPS is defined by Super classes and not by sub classes.
Basically the extends contract is defined as "is a" relationship where subclass is a object of Super class but not vice versa

Read it this way, MiniShuttle is a Shuttle but Shuttle is not a MiniShuttle

Answer (score 0):

You instantiated "shuttle" as a generic Shuttle object in line 1 of your main method, but then you tried to cast it to a MiniShuttle. You can't do that, because a Shuttle is not necessarily going to be a MiniShuttle, but something else. Here's another example that hopefully makes it clearer why that would be a bad assumption more concrete example illustrating why that's a bad assumption.

```
Shuttle ssQuark = new FerengiShuttle(); // a FerengiShuttle is also a Shuttle
MiniShuttle mshuttle = (MiniShuttle) ssQuark; // No!
```

A FerengiShuttle is a kind of shuttle, and mshuttle is also a shuttle, but ssQuark is not a MiniShuttle and was never intended to be. If you have a generic Shuttle object, you can't make the necessary assumptions required to downcast it.